# Reuse uuid in helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am writing helm charts and it creates one `deployment` and one `statefulset` component.

Now I want to generate uuid and send the value to both `k8s` components.

I a using `uuid` function to generate the uuid. But need help how I can send this value to both components.

Here is my chart folder structure --

- projectdir

  - chart1

    - templates

      - statefulset.yaml
  - chart2

    - templates

      - deployment.yaml
  - helperchart

    - templates

      - _helpers.tpl

I have to write the logic to generate the `uuid` in `_helpers.tpl`.

Comment: This question is very vague and doesn't contain any code or details. Please provide some more information so people can help you effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** It seems defining it in the `_helpers.tpl` does not work - thank you for pointing it out.

I have lookup it up a bit, and it seems currently the only way to achieve that is to put both of the manifests, separated by `---` to the same file under the `templates/`. See the following example, where the UUID is defined in the first line and then used in the both `Deployment` and the `StatefulSet`:

```yaml
{{- $mySharedUuid := uuidv4 -}}

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "uuid-test.fullname" . }}-1
  labels:
    {{- include "uuid-test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    my-uuid: {{ $mySharedUuid }}
spec:
...
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ include "uuid-test.fullname" . }}-2
  labels:
    {{- include "uuid-test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    my-uuid: {{ $mySharedUuid }}
spec:
...
```

After templating, the output is:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: uuid-test-app-1
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: uuid-test-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: uuid-test
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: uuid-test-app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    my-uuid: fe0346f5-a963-4ca1-ada0-af17405f3155
spec:
...
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: uuid-test-app-2
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: uuid-test-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: uuid-test
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: uuid-test-app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    my-uuid: fe0346f5-a963-4ca1-ada0-af17405f3155
spec:
...
```

See the same issue: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6456

Note that this approach **will still cause the UUID to be regenerated** when you do a **`helm upgrade`**. To circumvent that, you would need to use another workaround along with this one.

Comment: I tried the option. But it is giving the different UUID every time when it make a call.

Comment: @srr you are right - thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the answer to use a different approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. It looks we are closer to the solution. Unfortunately, I am not able to combine both components as I them in diff charts for a reason. I had updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly pass the value in as a Helm value; don't try to generate it in the chart.

The other answers to this question highlight a couple of the issues you'll run into.  [@UtkuÖzdemir notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143399/10008173) that every time you call the Helm [`uuidv4`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#uuid-functions) function it will create a new random UUID, so you can only call that function once in the chart ever; and [@srr further notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66174328/10008173) that there's no way to persist a generated value like this, so if you `helm upgrade` the chart the UUID value will be regenerated, which will cause all of the involved Kubernetes objects to be redeployed.

The [Bitnami RabbitMQ chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq) has an interesting middle road here.  One of its configuration options is an "Erlang cookie", also a random string that needs to be consistent across all replicas and upgrades.  On an initial install it generates a random value if one isn't provided, and tells you how to retrieve it from a Secret; but if `.Release.IsUpgrade` then you must provide the value directly, and the error message explains how to get it from your existing deployment.

You may be able to get around the "only call `uuidv4` once ever" problem by putting the value into a ConfigMap or Secret, and then referencing it from elsewhere.  This works only if the only place you use the UUID value is in an environment variable, or something else that can have a value injected from a secret; it won't help if you need it in an annotation or label.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "chart.name" . }}
data:
  the-uuid: {{ .Values.theUuid | default uuidv4 | b64enc }}
  {{-/*    this is the only place uuidv4 ^^^^^^ is called at all */}}
```

```yaml
env:
  - name: THE_UUID
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: {{ template "chart.name" . }}
        key: the-uuid
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details in depth with references. Unfortunately, I can't use any of your options due to following reasons - (1) I am fine even if `uuidv4` generates new string every time. But all I want same string must be used by deployment in chart 2 and statefulset in chart 1. (2) I am trying to make `uuid` generation part of code to avoid one additional manual task (3) ConfigMap/ Secret - If we define ConfigMap/Secret in chart 1, I am no sure if we can access from chart 2

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in helm issue tracker https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6456, we have to put both components in same file and looks like thats the only solution right now.

Its a surprise, Helm not supporting cache the value to share across charts/components. I wish Helm support this feature in future.