# Re-using UUID in helm configmap

Tags: kubernetes, uuid, configmap, helm3

There's a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143201/reuse-uuid-in-helm-charts) question that alludes to the possibility of auto-generating a uuid in helm charts when used as a secret or configmap. I'm trying precisely to do that, but I'm getting a new uuid each time.

My test case:

```
---
{{- $config := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" .Release.Namespace "{{ .Release.Name }}-testcase") -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-testcase"
  namespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}"
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
data:
{{- if $config }}
  TEST_VALUE: {{ $config.data.TEST_VALUE | quote }}
{{- else }}
  TEST_VALUE: {{ uuidv4 | quote }}
{{ end }}
```

I initially deploy this with:

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace test mytest .
```

If I run it again, or run with `helm diff upgrade --namespace test mytest .` I get a new value for `TEST_VALUE`. When I dump the contents of `$config` it's an empty map `{}`.

I'm using Helm v3.9.0, kubectl 1.24, and kube server is 1.22.

NOTE: I couldn't ask in a comment thread on the other post because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: According to [the fine manual](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function), helm will not contact k8s for `template` nor `dry-run` operations, and the behavior you're getting sounds suspiciously like the `template` case. Aside from that, the linked question talks about the way bitnami does it by checking for the IsUpgrade case -- why does that approach not work for you?

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I'm using this approach for connectors for [OpenCTI](https://www.opencti.io/en/). I will have potentially dozens of these things and tracking all the UUIDs in a `values.yml` file isn't appealing. The thing is I'm not using `template` nor `dry-run`, so I assume what I'm doing is supposed to work. I'm new enough to helm that it is not obvious to me if that's the case. Perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: Ok, then my other hypothesis is that using the quoted mustaches is not getting expanded; try `{{- $config := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" .Release.Namespace (printf "%s-testcase" .Release.Name)) -}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to my issue where you enclosed your stack overflow post : https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/11187

A way to make your configmap work is to save as a variable before conditionally set your value. This means every time you upgrade, you'll generate a UUID which will normally will not be used, but this is not dramatic.

When assigning an existing value, `:=` should become `=`. Also don't forget to b64enc your value in your manifest

```
{{- $config := uuidv4 | b64enc | quote -}}
{{- $config_lookup := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" .Release.Namespace "{{ .Release.Name }}-testcase") -}}
{{- if $config_lookup -}}
{{- $config = $config_lookup.data.TEST_VALUE -}}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-testcase"
  namespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}"
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
data:
  TEST_VALUE: {{ $config | quote }}
```

Comment: Ultimately, I used the `printf` approach suggested by mdaniel combined with this cleaner template approach. Note the `if` on line 3 requires and `end` and since this is a ConfigMap and not a Secret, the value doesn't have to be b64encoded.